# python asynchronous generator misunderstanding

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm new to `asyncio`, and particularly to asynchronous generator in Python.
Here is the basic code for which i do not understand the behavior. It is about simulating with an awaited sleep, the "get()" of yielded value from a remote database:

```
import asyncio

async def async_gen():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"entering iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(f"ending iteration {i}")
        yield i

async def main():
    async for value in async_gen():
        print(value)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I expect :

- the iteration `i` printing `entering iteration i`
- then awating the 3s sleeping and immediatly goes to next iteration `i+1` and printing `entering iteration i+1`

In other words, i expected all the `entering` printings to be immediate and after 3s, all the `ending` printings to be immediate. Total elapsed time should be 3s:

```
entering iteration 0
entering iteration 1
entering iteration 2
entering iteration 3
entering iteration 4
ending iteration 0
0
ending iteration 1
1
ending iteration 2
2
ending iteration 3
3
ending iteration 4
4
```

Instead, the execution provide the following with 3s between each `entering iteration i`/`ending iteration i` and total time is then 5*3s = 15s:

```
entering iteration 0
ending iteration 0
0
entering iteration 1
ending iteration 1
1
entering iteration 2
ending iteration 2
2
entering iteration 3
ending iteration 3
3
entering iteration 4
ending iteration 4
4
```

I'm sure there is something i'm not getting well.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks a lot

Regards

Comment: An async generator is just one that can `await` on behalf of the code iterating over it. It will not automatically introduce the kind of concurrency you expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the main() is the single task. If you want concurrency you have to create separate task for each iteration.

For example:

```
import asyncio


async def some_func(i: int):
    print(f"entering iteration {i}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"ending iteration {i}")


async def async_gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i


async def main():
    tasks = []

    async for value in async_gen():
        # launching concurrent task
        task = asyncio.create_task(some_func(value))
        tasks.append(task)

    # wait for all tasks to finish
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```